# How to display the hour and minutes if time is over in php

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

```
<span class="m-l-10 text-success text-center pull-right" style="font-size:11px;">                                                           
<? 
    $time_diff=strtotime($row['plannedDate'])-time();
    $minute=($time_diff/60);
    $hour=($minute/60);
    if($minute<=59){
        $follow_time= round($minute). ' minutes left';
    } elseif($hour <= 12){
        $follow_time= round($hour,0). ' hour left';
    }else{
        $follow_time=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['plannedDate']));
    }
    echo $follow_time;
?>
</span>
```

Here I have written some code to display the minutes left and hour left.

But I want to display the minutes left only for remaining minutes left for a meeting and I want to display both the hour and minutes over only if the time is over.

For example, I have allotted the PlannedDate like 2020-07-09 12:00:34 and it shows 28 minutes left this correct but if the PlannedDate time is over like -692 minutes left I want to show both hour and minutes over.

How to make this? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by showing hours and minutes left is over? Is it a count down timer?

Comment: For example if i set the plannedDate like this 2020-07-09 12:00:34 i want to show the minutes left like 16 minutes left but if i set the plannedDate like this 2020-07-09 00:00:19 i want to show the hr mnts over like this..

Comment: For negative minutes value i want to show the hour and minutes already over

Comment: Then why are you still showing 19 seconds if hours and minutes left is over?

Comment: Your question might benefit from an example of what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: I am not showing seconds here. i want to echo remaining minutes left for the 12 PM of today and i want to show the hours and minutes over for the 12 AM of today

Comment: I am not gettign your point jibsteroos

Comment: @Swethashetty Learn to tag people if there are more than 2 people in conversation. Also, you said `I am not showing seconds here`, then what does `00:00:19` mean?

Comment: @vivek_23 here i was just storing PlannedDate in the format of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 but displaying only the minutes and hours..

Comment: @Shwethashetty So, bottom line is if the current date is in future, you show how many hours and minutes left, else you want to show `00:00`. Right?

Comment: @vivek_23 see here 1. Presenation Scheduled By Shwetha @ 12.00 AM. 
2.Presenation Scheduled By Seema @ 1.00 PM. here for the first i want to display the hours and minutes over because already 12.00 AM over and i want to show the minutes left only for the second because time 1.00 PM will going to come right.

Comment: @ShwethaShetty What should that mean?

Comment: @vivek_23 if time is over echo hour and  minutes over otherwise show minutes left

Comment: @Shwethashetty Can you add a few input output examples by editing your post?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="m-l-10 text-success text-center pull-right" style="font-size:11px;">                                                           
<?php
    $time_diff=strtotime($row['plannedDate'])-time();
    $minute=($time_diff/60);
    $hour=($minute/60);
    if($minute<=59 && $minute >0){
        $follow_time= round($minute). ' minutes left';
    } elseif($hour <= 12 && $hour > 0){
        $follow_time= round($hour,0). ' hour left';
    }else{
        $hourOver = intdiv(abs($time_diff),3600);
        $minuteOver = intdiv(abs($time_diff)%3600,60);
        $minuteOver = str_pad($minuteOver, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $follow_time='started ' . $hourOver . ':' . $minuteOver . ' ago';
    }
    echo $follow_time;
?>
</span>
```